# Permanent redirection issue with post method in mobile app

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-services, redirect, post

We have one website called example.com. It is developed in the WordPress. This website also contains webservices for the mobile app built for android and iOS.

Now we have moved website to another domain called example.org. So I have set .htaccess rule to move all .com site request to .org.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=308]
```

It is working fine for the website redirection as well webservice call which used GET method. But it is not working with the **POST method** of the webserivce.

It is throwing below error.

```
Response:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: <html><head>
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: <title>308 Permanent Redirect</title>
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: </head><body>
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: <h1>Permanent Redirect</h1>
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: <p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.example.org/wp-json/custom-api/v3/login">here</a>.</p>
02-20 21:10:32.373 31443-31443/? I/System.out: </body></html>
```

Can someone help to set proper redirection which can use for GET and POST both methods in web and webservices?

Comment: It is not working in the webservice call from mobile app. it is working from browser.

Comment: If it works from browser then rule is not the problem. You may some wordpress plugin handling mobile web requests differently.